# Show a list of names for all git projects

Tags: magit, helm, git

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm, Magit

I have many git projects in different folders.
Is it possible to show list of names for all git projects in one buffer?

Answer (score 7):

One existing approach is: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Repository-List.html#Repository-List. After setting `magit-repository-directories`, you can use `M-x magit-list-repositories` to display these repositories.

---

Here is my setting.

```
(setq magit-repository-directories
        '(("~/.emacs.d"                . 0)
          ("~/.emacs.d/straight/repos" . 1)
          ("~/src"                     . 1)))
```

Here is a screenshot of `M-x magit-list-repositories`.

[image: Screenshot of M-x magit-list-repositories]

Answer (score 2):

One option would be via [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile). Git repos are considered projects by default. Doing `M-x projectile-switch-project` or `C-c p p` lists all git repos. This may not be the solution you're after and there is probably a better way but it works well for me if I haven't added a directory to my bookmarks.